# Questions about a multi setup RAID and NAS together?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, raid, nas, video-editing

So here's the idea:

I want to run a 8TB M.2 PCIE 4.0 3 disk setup on top then down bottom I am considering my options.
I am thinking about doing a NAS Setup with a RAID 1 Array together.

The total storage would be 14TB available down below and the 8 TB M.2 for running programs.
The M.2's will be holding current editing files, gaming, software and project files.
The Storage below will be holding all the old projects, system backups, Old video, perhaps another installation of windows.

The questions I wanna ask:
Have I gone overboard with the storage?

Is it safe to run RAID and NAS together?

Have I got the right array type?

What brand drives would be ideal for this?

What size cache would be ideal?

How Would you recommend I run this safely?

Comment: Software RAID [ZFS] is better than hardware RAID is almost every, if not every, way. If running a NAS, using [TrueNAS](https://www.truenas.com/) as the OS would be recommended, as it's one of the best, if not the best, NAS OS in existence _(built upon FreeBSD, it uses ZFS by default, is highly configurable, supports Docker and VMs [jails], plugins, etc. - it's recommended to have at least 32GB of RAM when using TrueNAS)_. More information and hardware recommendations can be found on the [TrueNAS Forum](https://www.truenas.com/community/)

Comment: There is a big imbalance between your four sentences of system description and your six questions asked. Your system description lacks the needed specificity and does not allow answers. You do not specify your operating system, the intended file systems to use.

You might read across this site to see how others are asking specific questions and how much documentation they provide.

Answer (score 0):

Your question references "top" and "bottom". These terms do not, AFAIK have meaning with respect of RAID - making it difficult to understand your use case.

To answer your questions -

A NAS is a Network Storage device. Most (but not all) NAS's run some kind of RAID.

You have not described your question in terms relevant to RAID. I dont think RAID will do what I suspect you want. RAID1 certainly won't. RAID1 is typically 2 (or more) identical disks with only 1 drives worth of space available.

Product recommendations are off topic here, and hd brands are contentious.  Backup Blaze does/did lots of studies on their hard drive failures. You might want to read their reports.

The larger the cache the faster reads will appear to occur on stuff accessed, as its pulling off memory or fast disk.

Your last question is unanswerable.

Comment: Depending on your hardware you may want to look at something like ZFS. This can perform "RAID like" functions and use fast disks to cache content.  It has some hardware (and significant) RAM requirements and is not as widely used as RAID.  It aldo has a very steep learning curve.

Comment: An altermative - on a Linux based NAS might be to use LVM (maybe on top of RAID, or possibily in place of it) to manage your disks.  This also has a steep learning curve - LVM is fairly easy, its the caching and trade-offs combining resourcrs that are highly advanced)

Comment: ZFS isn't RAID-like, it's [_software RAID_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS), which is far better than antiquated hardware RAID in almost every, if not every, aspect _(especially it's self-healing filesystem)_. ZFS is widely used by consumers [TrueNAS/FreeBSD] and businesses & datacenters [TrueNAS Enterprise / TrueNAS SCALE], including over a third of Fortune 500 companies, via systems built by [iXsystems](https://www.ixsystems.com) _(the private developer who created and maintains the opensource [TrueNAS](https://www.truenas.com/) OS (formerly FreeNAS), which is built upon FreeBSD)_.

Comment: @jw0914 I think we agree except for symantics. To me, ZFS/RAIDZ is not quite software RAID, in the same way that LVM mirrors are not quite software RAID. (FWIW I run a ZFS box and dont like it, even though it is unquestionably technically superior to LVM on RAID - I like my block devices distinct from my filesystem - zvols notwithstanding). I can also argue RAIDZ - like JBOD is not RAID  because its not recognised as a RAID type/level by SNIA - the body that degines RAID standards

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run a 8TB M.2 PCIE 4.0 3 disk setup on top then down bottom

Please provide internet sources that explain your meaning of "top" and "bottom".

> I am considering my options. I am thinking about doing a NAS Setup with a RAID 1 Array together.

NAS machines are not suitable for your gaming requirements.

> The total storage would be 14TB available down below and the 8 TB M.2 for running programs. The M.2's will be holding current editing files

Which files, letters in word or interstellar video recording streams?

> , gaming, software and project files.

Project files? That does not sound like it is requiring lots of ressources.

> The Storage below will be holding all the old projects,

Mysterious projects.

> system backups, Old video, perhaps another installation of windows.

A NAS as a dual boot installation?

> The questions I wanna ask: Have I gone overboard with the storage?

This is opionion-based and can be discarded.

> Is it safe to run RAID and NAS together?

"Is it safe to" is a synonym for "Does that relieve from using a backup?". No, that is never safe.

> Have I got the right array type?

No answer due to unsufficient load description.

> What brand drives would be ideal for this?

Read the answer of user davidgo.

> What size cache would be ideal?

No answer due to unsufficient load description.

> How Would you recommend I run this safely?

This is again opinion-based and my statement above applies as well:
"Is it safe to" is a synonym for "Does that relieve from using a backup?". No, that is never safe.